# prestodb JDBC interpreter raises NullPointerException

Tags: apache-zeppelin, presto

I'm trying to connect to prestodb from Zeppelin using the generic JDBC interpreter. Here's the configuration:

```
presto %jdbc (default)
Option Shared

Properties
name    value
default.driver  com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver
default.url     jdbc:presto://presto:8080
default.user    presto
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.max_connection     10
zeppelin.jdbc.concurrent.use    true
Dependencies
artifact    exclude
/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/presto-jdbc-0.157.jar
```

I can successfully connect and query using the CLI:

`./presto --server presto:8080`

But when I try to use any query inside a notebook paragraph I get:

```
null
class java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.getMaxResult(JDBCInterpreter.java:471)
org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:307)
org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:408)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there something missing in my JDBC interpreter configuration?

Comment: My guess is the open source Presto JDBC driver is missing an implementation for some method that Zeppelin is calling.  Can you check the source to JDBCInterpreter to determine which method is providing a null, and then file an issue in the Presto project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was a simple configuration issue. Looking at the code for `getMaxResult`:

```
propertiesMap.get(COMMON_KEY).getProperty(MAX_LINE_KEY, MAX_LINE_DEFAULT));
```

So I suspected JDBC interpreters had some configuration that I forgot to include on my presto interpreter. Looking for the keywords `COMMON` and `MAX`, there was it:

```
common.max_count    1000
```

Adding this property to the presto interpreter solved this problem.